# trying to add two (2) wifi monitoring in CONKY

Tags: conky, network-monitoring

I'm currently using this part of my `conkyrc` code to monitor one of my WIFI's in a CONKY widget, but I want to monitor both of the two (2) wifi devices (wlp2s0 and wlx8416f91d3f6d) - any ideas?

```
${font Ubuntu:bold:size=10}NETWORK ${hr 2}
${font sans-serif:normal:size=8}Local IPs:${alignr}External IP:
${execi 1000 ip a | grep inet | grep -vw lo | grep -v inet6 | cut -d \/ -f1 | sed 's/[^0-9\.]*//g'}  ${alignr}${execi 1000  wget -q -O- http://ipecho.net/plain; echo}
${font sans-serif:normal:size=8}Down: ${downspeed wlx8416f91d3f6d}  ${alignr}Up: ${upspeed wlx8416f91d3f6d}
${color lightgray}${downspeedgraph wlx8416f91d3f6d 80,130 } ${alignr}${upspeedgraph wlx8416f91d3f6d 80,130 }$color
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: Widget is only monitoring the one WIFI, and not the other... must be some way to get both to be monitored with CONKY. 
- - - - - - - - - 
The PCI internal wifi sometimes goes out after waking from suspend and I switch to my USB wifi...

Comment: Make your `execi` command smarter. Your expression should return 1 value or the other (can you have a 2nd `execi` line?) or both, and handle that. The rest of the lines containing the interface name could be duplicated with  the other interface name.

Comment: Thanks for the hint...

Answer (score 0):

This code did the trick!

${font Ubuntu:bold:size=10}NETWORK ${hr 2}
${font sans-serif:normal:size=8}Local IPs:${alignr}External IP:
${execi 1000 ip a | grep inet | grep -vw lo | grep -v inet6 | cut -d / -f1 | sed 's/[^0-9.]*//g'}  ${alignr}${execi 1000  wget -q -O- http://ipecho.net/plain; echo}
${font sans-serif:normal:size=8}Down: ${downspeed wlx8416f91d3f6d}  ${alignr}Up: ${upspeed wlx8416f91d3f6d}
${color lightgray}${downspeedgraph wlx8416f91d3f6d 40,150 } ${alignr}${upspeedgraph wlx8416f91d3f6d 40,150 }$color
${font sans-serif:normal:size=8}Down: ${downspeed wlp2s0}  ${alignr}Up: ${upspeed wlp2s0}
${color lightgray}${downspeedgraph wlp2s0 40,150 } ${alignr}${upspeedgraph wlp2s0 40,150 }$color

Here's my CONKY Widget now:

[image: My CONKY Widget:]